# Sublime Text 3 package control is not installing, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: installation, sublimetext3, package-control

I installed package control before and am currently using Emmet in Sublime Text 3 fine, but I am trying to install a new package control for syntax highlighting in Laravel, but I am having trouble installing package control when I paste in the installation code.

And when I got press control+shift+P and look for Package Control, nothing is there.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I couldn't figure out what was wrong so I just did a fresh install of Sublime Text 3 and everything worked out fine.

Answer (score 2):

Check your User Preferences and make sure that the `ignored_packages` array does not include `"Package Control"`.  That's happened to me a few times when moving between dev builds, for reasons that are entirely unclear.